# What does create! mean in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does this do in Rails?

```
create! do |user| 
  #initialise user 
end
```

I figured it creates a user objects and saves it to the database. How is it different from just saying `user.new(...)` and `user.save()`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**In a nutshell:**

- `create!` raises an exception while `create` returns the object (unsaved object if it does not pass validations).
- `save!` raises an error while `save` returns `true`/`false`.
- `save` does not take attributes, `create` does.

`new` does not save. `new` is similar to `build` in `ActiveRecord` context.
`create` saves to the database and returns `true` or `false` depending on model validations.
`create!` saves to the database but raises an exception if there are errors in model validations (or any other error).

Comment: I upvoted because this is a good answer. However, `create` does not return a boolean. It returns the object instance whether it passed validation or not.

Comment: @AdityaSanghi - thank you for your answer. you say: " create! saves to the database but raises an exception if there are errors in model validations (or any other error)."  --------> how can it save anything to the database if the validations are not passed?

Comment: @bkspurgeon it doesnt save if validations fails. The bang method behaves differently in case of failure from the non-bang version. Bang version raises exception and non-bang version returns false.

Answer (score 4):

When failed to create record, `create!` throws an exception, `new` and then `save` (or just `create` without exclamation mark) exit silently.

Answer (score -2):

`create` takes attributes , so using a block here is somewhat unusual.
The code you mention is doing the initialization in a block that is passed to `create!`
It is in principal the same as `new` followed by the initialization and then a `save!`

There are many variations save, save!, create, ceate!, update, update!, etc., 
there are also variations in terms of validations, and call-backs

For details please check the API: (it is discussed in the first link)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: slightly wrong. create/create!/save/save! are all subtly different. create/create! take model attributes. save/save! dont take in model attribute parameters. methods with bang (create!/save!) raise exception on validation failure and methods without bang (create/save) dont.

Comment: also save doesnt returns nil, it returns the result of the validations (true or false).

Comment: that is ridiculous. I never said that `save` would take arguments.
I did point to the relevant documentation - how is that wrong??